# Full outer join with a list in oracle

Tags: oracle, join, select

I have a table `test`:

```
id    number
name  varchar2(20)
ddate varchar2(20)
```

I want to select all row from `test` on specepic date and full outter join with a list of values. For example let's say this is the data:

```
SQL> select * from test;

id     name     ddate
---    ----     ------
1      a        20-02-18
2      b        21-02-18
3      c        21-02-18
4      d        22-02-18
```

I want this result:

```
SQL> --of course this doesn't work.
SQL> select * 
from test full outter join ('b','e') list on test.name=list.name 
where ddate='20-02-18';

id     name     ddate
---    ----     ------
null   e        null
2      b        21-02-18
3      c        21-02-18
```

Comment: Do you really store the dates as VARCHAR and in `DD-MM-YY` format?

Comment: Of course not..

Comment: Then why is the `VARCHAR(20)` in this question?

Comment: Because it's not relevent, change the date string to letters if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Not something I would recommend doing, but:

```
select test.id, nvl(test.name, list.column_value) as name, test.ddate
from
  test 
  full outer join table(sys.odcivarchar2list('b', 'e')) list
on test.name = list.column_value
where nvl(ddate, date'2018-02-21') = date'2018-02-21'
order by id nulls first
;

        ID NAME       DDATE               
---------- ---------- --------------------
           e                              
         2 b          21-FEB-18           
         3 c          21-FEB-18
```

Comment: Why not? There aren't other method?

Comment: this `odcivarchar2list` saved the day